# convert int to char array Big Endian

Tags: c, arrays, endianness

I found this code on SO.

```
unsigned char * SerializeInt(unsigned char *buffer, int value)
{
  /* Write big-endian int value into buffer; assumes 32-bit int and 8-bit char. */
  buffer[0] = value >> 24;
  buffer[1] = value >> 16;
  buffer[2] = value >> 8;
  buffer[3] = value;
  return buffer + 4;
}
```

You can see the code claims it is writing an integer into the buffer, in a Big Endian Way.

My question is: Does this function work correctly on both Little endian and Big endian machines? **In other words, on both LE and BE machines, does it store the number to buffer in a Big Endian Way**? And if yes, Why?

Comment: No, it only works correctly on big endian machine.

Comment: @leeduhem: Aha, that was my point. That is why I asked I am not sure either.. But I started to have doubts that it may work on both BE and LE machines

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever is the endianness of your system, your `SerializeInt` function will store `value` in big endian in the array `buffer`. It is stored as big endian as it writes the most significant byte first. Remember that when you evaluate `value` it has no endianness *per se*, it's like any mathematical value.

Comment: Yes my judgement was going in that direction too... Bit more elaboration would be welcome though as to why

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking that it had to do with `value` ... like integer 14 is 14 both on BE and LE machines, ... that is the point right? (and doing `value >> 24` will always yield MSB?)

Comment: @dmcr_code a value has no endianness, endianness is the way you'll store a value in a multi-bytes array. If `value` is a 32-bit quantity then yes `value >> 24` is the MSB whatever the endianness of the system is.

Answer (score 1):

The code will always write the `integer` in `char` array in big-endian way. This is because you are always saving MSB at `buffer[0]` and LSB at `buffer[3]`.

Suppose in a little endian machine:

you have number `0x11223344`: (in hexadecimal format)

```
Address      ->      2003  2002  2001  2000

`int` Number ->       11    22    33    44
Buffer       ->   index[3]  [2]   [1]   [0]
```

The same representation on a big endian machine will be:

```
Address      ->      2000  2001  2002  2003  <= See only the addressing changed/reversed

`int` Number ->       11    22    33    44
Buffer       ->   index[3]  [2]   [1]   [0]
```

In both machines, `integer << 24` will mean MSB and `(int8_t)integer` will mean LSB.

Answer (score 0):

Big-Endian is defined as **with the big end (i.e. most significant bit/byte) first**. So, yes, the function writes the `value` in big-endian format to the `buffer`.

However, returning a pointer one past the buffer strikes me as unusual.

Comment: You can write the next value in the location immediately following what you just wrote

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the already posted answers regarding endianess...

> Does this function work correctly on both Little endian and Big endian machines?

No, because you use bit-wise arithmetic on the default `int` type. If the `int` is negative, the behavior is implementation-defined. In general, it doesn't make any sense whatsoever to use bit-wise operators on signed integers.

Furthermore, your code relies on `int` being 32 bits, of which there are no guarantees.

So your code is completely non-portable. Fix it in the following way:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint8_t* SerializeInt (uint8_t* buffer, uint32_t value)
```