# MD5 - add message length

Tags: c, byte, md5

I would like to create block for MD5 algorithm. This is my code:

```
uint8_t buffer[64];
for (int i = size + 1; i < 56; i++)
    buffer[i] = 0;
```

But I don't know how can I add message length on the last 64bits. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared `buffer` of length 8, how come you expect this to work:

```
for (int i = size + 1; i < 56; i++)
    buffer[i] = 0;
```

Out of bounds access?

Ok you said from 56th element you want to store length. Why not
do something like this:

```
memcpy(&buffer[56], &length, sizeof(int)); // you may want to check sizeof(int) on your machine to know how many bytes were written
```

but you should be careful about endianness. This will write the `length` according to the endianness your machine has. If you want to store it in some particular endianness maybe you can do it manually using bit wise operators. Check some more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544928/reading-integer-size-bytes-from-a-char-array), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22400511/convert-int-to-char-array-big-endian)

If you want `length` to have fixed size, you can declare it as `uint32_t` and use 4 as last parameter in `memcpy` directly.

Comment: @Bakus123: what is value of `size`?

Comment: Size = message length (from 1 to 10). It's integer.

Comment: @Bakus123: I am sorry the question as it stands now I don't exactly understand what you want to achieve. btw md5 output length is 16 bytes; if you can make it more clear ..

Comment: I want create 512bit block where first bits = message, next is 0x80 and zeros until 448 bit and next(last bits) = message length.

Comment: How can I do the same using bitwise operators (I use little endian)? Because i write program on GPU and I'm not sure if memory references it's good idea for me...

Comment: In your code I get error - "subscript out of range"

Comment: @Bakus123: please check that link for endianness I gave. about out of range that should not happen your buffer is 64 bytes so there should be space for 8 more bytes. please look at how memcpy is used also

Comment: @Bakus123:I added another link about endianness in answer

Comment: Thx for link. I received error: "subscript out of range" because I had buffer[8]. But I have one problem yet. When I use uint8_t *bytes = (uint8_t*)malloc(64); it works but when I use uint8_t bytes[64]; it doesn't works. What is different? I prefer second way because og GPU I shouldn't use malloc.

Comment: I get wrong MD5 hash.I'm checking it accurately now.

Comment: @Bakus123: It really should not have to do with whether you allocate it as pointer (first example) or on the stack(uint8_t bytes[64]); usage is mostly similar

Comment: I made pritf in loop and in case without malloc on 61 and 62 bits are values other tan 0 but I don't know why... the rest is the same

Comment: @Bakus123: really can't tell maybe you can ask other question about that; but like I said their usage is mostly similar you should not get that difference